# Website with optimal cache control

Tags: .htaccess, cache, http-headers

**My goal**

I would like to let browsers cache my whole website, but only download the new information when I have changed one or more files.

**My situation**
After some research I have found a way to do this. That is to add a `Far Future Expires Header` to my htaccess file and add a querystring to my files using the `filemtime()` function.

**The problem**

When I click on the address bar and type in my website address in firefox, then Firebug displays 
`38.3 KB (36.4 KB from cache)`

When I press F5 in firefox, then Firebug displays:
`241.1 KB (10.9 KB from cache)`

Now I have tried to do the same with Google and they are sending HTTP header 304 back. I have read a lot about ETag and the Last Modified header, but I have heard a lot of people saying that they are not really reliable.

**My question**

What would be the best solution if I would like to send HTTP header 304 back if the user presses on F5, like Google?

**Update**

It seems that Firefox is controlling the way the cache is used and I would like to use the cache also when a user presses F5.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested @symcbean, and is the recommended practice to  use unique URLs to avoid any problem with stale/new content. Anyway to eliminate the 304 requests remove the ETags and Last-Modified tag.

The URL below provides good tips for speeding/caching web pages. 
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-last-modified.html

Answer (score 0):

When you use Apache2 there is a module called ["mod-expires"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) we use it here for caching. The module set the expire header for the requests.

Comment: Did you read my question?

Comment: Yes i have read it ;) and you want an answer. We use it here. Expire header and Etags. And when you use expire headers you get 304 not modified. @Z0q

Comment: When you use expire headers, the browser won't even send requests to the server, so they won't return a 304 header. That will only be sent when you are using ETags or the Last-Modified header.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid conditional requests - unless you are serving up large volumes of very large files (such as videos) then they can actually make your site much slower.

> that they are not really reliable.

IME, they are very reliable - but also very inefficient.

> but only download the new information when I have changed one or more files.

Don't change files - create new URLs for the new content. You can't rescind caching information already issued.

> That is to add a Far Future Expires Header to my htaccess file and add a querystring to my files using the filemtime() function

Oh - sorry, you're already doing that.

Pressing f5 in your browser is not a realistic way to measure cacheability.

Yes you can make a 304 response if the browser makes a **conditional request** and the conditions are met by the current content - but as above it's not a good way of dealing with the situation - consider you have a spot graphic appearing 4 times on a page. After the cache has expired, the browser will send 4 conditional requests to the origin each time this page is loaded. While you can send new caching instructions in a 304 response, it's usually not very easy to do this in practice. Remember latency is far more of a problem than bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer. So you would suggest to keep the Far Future Expires Header and the querystring with `filemtime()`, but to unset the `Last-Modified` header?

Comment: Yes - and (assuming this apache 2.0 or later) use mod_headers to remove if-modified-since and if-none-match from request